# What does "this" point to?

Tags: java

Not a duplicate,  This is a semantics question?

A professor at Columbia said it, the keyword `this`, points to the current `class` ( [See Page 21](http://www.cs.nyu.edu/~cconway/teaching/cs1007/notes/oop.pdf) ).  I'm 99% sure this is not correct.

I would like to say it passes to a `class instance` or an `object`.  Is there a preferred way to say what `this` points to concisely.

Thanks, I just want my notes to be accurate.

Comment: Yes, those notes are wrong.  `this` refers to the current **instance**.

Comment: The wording is inaccurate, but the professor probably meant the right thing

Comment: The Java language spec (JLS) itself: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.8.3.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From the [Oracle docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.8.3):

> The keyword **this** may be used only in the body of an instance method,
>   instance initializer, or constructor, or in the initializer of an
>   instance variable of a class. If it appears anywhere else, a
>   compile-time error occurs.

...

> When used as a primary expression, the keyword this denotes a value
>   that is a reference to the object for which the instance method was
>   invoked (§15.12), or to the object being constructed.

From the [wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Java_keywords):

> **this**
>
> Used to represent an instance of the class in which it appears. this
>   can be used to access class members and as a reference to the current
>   instance. The **this** keyword is also used to forward a call from one
>   constructor in a class to another constructor in the same class.

Comment: When used as a primary expression, the keyword this denotes a value that is a reference to the object for which the instance method was invoked (§15.12), or to the object being constructed.

Comment: Do you know how to make the `§` sign? I just copy pasted it but I need to know how to make it from the keyboard?

Answer (score 1):

### What does "this" point to?

`this`  refers to the `current object`.

E.g

```
public class MyThisTest {
  private int a;

  public MyThisTest() {
    this(42); // calls the other constructor
  }

  public MyThisTest(int a) {
    this.a = a; // assigns the value of the parameter a to the field of the same name
  }

  public void frobnicate() {
    int a = 1;

    System.out.println(a); // refers to the local variable a
    System.out.println(this.a); // refers to the field a
    System.out.println(this); // refers to this entire object
  }

  public String toString() {
    return "MyThisTest a=" + a; // refers to the field a
  }
}
```

**Self Explanatory Output:**

```
1
42
MyThisTest a=42
```

Answer (score 0):

`this` is a keyword used by the `OO programming languages` to refer to the instance of `current class`. *It implicitly fetches the the reference or the address of the object or instance of the current class.*

`this` in [JAVA](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/thiskey.html)

Hope this helps

Comment: it does look cleaner in certain OO languages. For instance in `C++` instead of passing the refrence like **&obj**, it relatively looks better to pass **this** instead

Comment: How could you pass a reference to the current object using &obj?

Answer (score 0):

You can think of it as the "current class". But I like to think of it as a reference to the object instance in which the "this" is used.

So if you have class A and you create two instances, A1 and A2, when you refer to "this" in a method call executing in A2, "this" refers to the instance A2, not the class A.

Clear as mud?

Answer (score 0):

`this` definitely refers to the current instance